# Debugger not stop on breakpoint

Tags: django, docker, visual-studio-code, debugpy

I'm trying to debug my Docker Django app with this configuration.

launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Docker: Python - Django",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "connect": {
        "port": 5678,
        "host": "0.0.0.0",
      },
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "remoteRoot": "/project"
        }
      ],
      "django": true,
      "justMyCode": false
  }
}
```

docker-compose.debug.yml.py:

```
...
django:
  extends:
    file: docker-compose.yml
    service: django
  command: sh -c "DEBUG_MODE=True python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --noreload"
  ports:
    - "5678:5678"
```

manage.py:

```
...
if os.environ.get("DEBUG_MODE", False):
    import debugpy

    debugpy.listen(("0.0.0.0", 5678))
    debugpy.wait_for_client()
```

I run docker compose with the debug file, the program waits to execute the vscode configuration but when I go to url the execution does not stop at the breakpoint.

Output:

> Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off to python to disable frozen modules.

Changing the command `sh -c "DEBUG_MODE=True python -Xfrozen_modules=off manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --noreload"`doesn´t work either.

Any sugestion?